# SMARTGWT show prompt on blur event

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I need to show the prompt message of a textbox item using `setPrompt("msg")` when user try to enter an invalid value.

I tried using `fireEvent(new MouseOverEvent(bandwidth_eir.getJsObj()));` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to show promt? You can also show error message.

Comment: If prompt I can control clearprompt() after some matter of seconds without user interaction

Comment: The same thing you can also achieve with error messages. You can use `clearErrors` to wipe them out after a time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a Validator to the TextBoxtItem with the custom error message you need.

Then in the form setShowInlineErrors(true) and just validate the form before submit.